# Laravel Form Return then Redirect

Tags: laravel, forms, redirect

I'm still getting to grips with laravel, and I imagine this has a straightforward fix, but I can't seem to find anything for it.
I want submit my form, have the data returned through the create and then redirect to another page rather than displaying my form results. Currently it just returns an empty page with the email and name variables and adds it to the db.

I've tried the below in adduser controller but it doesn't action the create function through my db and just redirects me.

```
   return Child::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),           
   ]) && Redirect::to('/anotherpage');
```

Do I have to do something with my controller or can this be done with a variant of the above?

Comment: You don't need to return the result of the create method. Returning just ends the execution of the method, so call `Child::create` then `return Redirect...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `redirect()` function with data

```
$child = Child::create([
    'name' => $request->input('name'),
    'email' => $request->input('email'),           
]);

// in route() function first parameter is the route name,
// second parameter is the data array.
return redirect(route('another_page', ['child' => $child]));
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end I didn't need to store the child in an array and did as @joe suggested just running the child::create and then return redirect()->action('manageusersController@index');